# Check availability of foreign key value in the foreign table

Tags: yii

Say I have 2 tables, A and B.
B has a foreign key from A.
Whenever I insert data to table B, I should check availability of foreign key in the table A.
Is there any way to do this process instead of doing it manually ?

---

I have googled it by myself, and found that CExistValidator is probably what I want.
But I didn't find any comprehensive example for use of that validator.
If CExistValidator is the answer, can you give me some example ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a class `Category` which has many `Page`s. You want to ensure that `Page` belongs to some existing `Category`:

```
class Page {
  //...
  public function rules()
  {
    return array(
      array('category_id', 'exist', 'className' => 'Category', 'attributeName' => 'id'),
    );
  }
}
```